# Error: "Copying the source file <Unknown>"

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, findbugs

I am working on a Jenkins project on a shared server managed by my school. My `build.xml` file has the following relevant steps for the FindBugs execution:

```
<target name="findbugs">
    <echo>FindBugs Starting:</echo>

    <available file="${findbugs.dir}/findbugs.jar" property="findbugs.available" />
    <fail unless="findbugs.available" message="Error: FINDBUGS_HOME not set or findbugs.jar not found." />

    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask" classpath="${findbugs.dir}/findbugs-ant.jar" />
    <findbugs home="${findbugs.dir}"
        workHard="true"
        output="xml:withMessages"
        outputFile="${report.dir}/findbugs.xml"
        excludefilter="findbugs-exclusions.xml"
        sourcePath="${src.dir}" >
        <class location="${classes.dir}" />
        <auxClasspath>
            <fileset file="${lib.dir}/junit.jar" />
        </auxClasspath>
     </findbugs>

    <echo>FindBugs finished</echo>
</target>
```

When executed, the output on the Jenkins console contains no errors, but shows a clean execution as far as I can tell:

```
     [echo] FindBugs Starting:
 [findbugs] Executing findbugs from ant task
 [findbugs] Running FindBugs...
 [findbugs] Warnings generated: 24
 [findbugs] Calculating exit code...
 [findbugs] Setting 'bugs found' flag (1)
 [findbugs] Exit code set to: 1
 [findbugs] Java Result: 1
 [findbugs] Output saved to report/findbugs.xml
     [echo] FindBugs finished
```

In the results of the FindBugs warnings under the "Files" tab, there is a file listed named "", and within that detail I see the following:

```
 com.ewenicorn.reddit.dailyprogrammer.utility.CharacterUtilityTest.testShiftCharacter() invokes inefficient new Character(char) constructor; use Character.valueOf(char) instead
01 Copying the source file 'com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/utility/<Unknown>' from the workspace to the build folder '/home/VLE/1257538/jenkins/jobs/RedditDailyProgrammer/builds/2013-08-24_16-50-28/workspace-files/f2082c83.tmp' on the Jenkins master failed.
02 Seems that the path is relative, however an absolute path is required when copying the sources.
03 Is the file '<Unknown>' contained more than once in your workspace?
04 Is the file 'com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/utility/<Unknown>' a valid filename?
05 If you are building on a slave: please check if the file is accessible under '$JENKINS_HOME/[job-name]/com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/utility/<Unknown>'
06 If you are building on the master: please check if the file is accessible under '$JENKINS_HOME/[job-name]/workspace/com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/utility/<Unknown>'
07 hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/utility/<Unknown> at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@4d948ad7
08   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:905)
09   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
10   at hudson.FilePath.copyTo(FilePath.java:1776)
11   at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.copyFilesWithAnnotationsToBuildFolder(HealthAwareRecorder.java:398)
12   at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:165)
13   at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.perform(HealthAwareRecorder.java:333)
14   at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
15   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
16   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
17   at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
18   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:726)
19   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1628)
20   at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
21   at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
22   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
23 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/utility/<Unknown> (No such file or directory)
24   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
25   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
26   at hudson.FilePath$34.invoke(FilePath.java:1781)
27   at hudson.FilePath$34.invoke(FilePath.java:1776)
28   at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2417)
29   at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
30   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:898)
31   ... 14 more
```

I am looking to resolve this error, so any help available is appreciated, especially since I have not found anything from prior folks researching this issue. If the additional structure is needed, the full source and binaries of the file can be found at https://github.com/jenrmagas/RedditDailyProgrammer, and it should work out of the box for a build with Ant.

Comment: I created a jenkins freestyle job for your git project, added a ant build with target 'main', added a findbugs post build action, and jenkins (1.525) generated the findbugs graph.

I also have the "com.ewenicorn.reddit.dailyprogrammer.utility - File <Unknown>" file but it doesn't create issues.

Could you specify: your jenkins version, the findbugs version used, your platform, whether you are using distributed build or not.

Note: I had to edit src/com/ewenicorn/reddit/dailyprogrammer/intermediate/incomplete/Problem011UpsideUpNumbers.java as it contains non UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the start - I agree that the Problem011UpsideUpNumbers.java has issues, and I'm keeping it there for now as an example of an issue to correct later (part of the project, and it shouldn't impact this). Anyway, I'm working on Jenkins 1.528 with FindBugs 4.50, theoretically on a RedHat or equivalent distro (though I can't see it, I've definitely got *NIX-like paths). I actually upgraded to the latest Jenkins + plugins I could get to avoid version issues. This was also a freestyle job, nothing fancy. I'm seeing 1 listed 'Warning' in the results, which is my concern.

Comment: I have the same problem, have Googled extensively and find no answer. However, I have found that if you go click on the "warnings" link in the left column, rather than clicking on on the chart and then click on the "new" tab then you can drill down into the code. This is the only way that works for me. Can you please confirm if it works for you? Thanks.

Comment: Could be that this question is invalid. The problem is not with the copying. I checked the findbugs_report.xml for cases where this happens to me as well. It contains lines like this: <ClassStats class="com.actix.geotagging3.test.io.MonkitXMLFileWriter$MonkitXMLFileWriterTest" sourceFile="&lt;Unknown&gt;" interface="false" size="16" bugs="1" priority_2="1"/>, which means that Jenkins could only fail.

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown source file" is most likely due to code being compile without the debug information.